# jsonb existential operators with parameterised queries

Tags: php, json, postgresql, pdo, jsonb

...or the question mark question.

I am currently implementing the search functionality for a postgres database, in php, that uses the new jsonb type.

To achieve this I am executing prepared statements with named placeholders.

However I have run into an interesting problem whilst trying to use some of the new postgres [JSON containment and existence operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-OP-TABLE) along with named placeholders.

The basis of issue being that the operators themselves use the question mark `?` as part of their syntax. i.e.

`?` Does the key/element string exist within the JSON value?

`?|` Do any of these key/element strings exist?

`?&` Do all of these key/element strings exist?

This means I have statements that look like this in PHP.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE meta ? :value");
$sth->bindValue(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

This fails because the question mark is being interpreted as placeholder.
To work around this I have tried to make the operator itself a named parameter like so.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE meta :operator :value");
$sth->bindValue(1, $operator, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->bindValue(2, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

However this just throws the same error as using the bare operator, i.e.

`ERROR:  syntax error at or near \"$1\"1`

Has anyone else come across this issue or can anyone think of a good workaround?

Is there a way to escape or pass the question mark so that one can use the postgres jsonb containment and existence operators with PDO parameterized queries?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can use corresponding functions instead of operators (jsonb_exists, jsonb_exists_any, jsonb_exists_all). for example run `\do+ "?"` in psql to see function name of ? operator.

or define your own operator without "?" symbol instead.

For example:

```
CREATE OPERATOR ~@ (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text, PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists)    
CREATE OPERATOR ~@| (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text[], PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists_any)
CREATE OPERATOR ~@& (LEFTARG = jsonb, RIGHTARG = text[], PROCEDURE = jsonb_exists_all)
```

So that one can use `~@`, `~@|` and `~@&` in place of `?`, `?|` and `?&` respectively. e.g.

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE meta ~@ :value");
$sth->bindValue(1, $value, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth->execute();
```

Comment: Ha! Really hadn't thought of that yet, will try it out now, many thanks!

Comment: Brilliant, operator definition is an ideal solution as it means I can use the same structure without having to deal with any function calls. Really appreciate it, had been scratching my head for a good few hours thinking about it from the PDO end rather than the db end. Again, many thanks.

Comment: Note. In documentation there is no functions like jsonb_exists, jsonb_exists_any, jsonb_exists_all but they actually work like jsonb_exists(jsonb, text)

Comment: @Swaok - yes see LEFTARG and RIGHTARG - they define the types for the PROCEDURE.

Comment: Index on jsonb field is not used with this approach

Comment: https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/1967 a fix is finally on the way (at the time of writing)

Comment: @mnv also not when using built-in jsonb_exists functions? or you mean when creating custom operator instead