# In gorm, how do you escape the `?` operator in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, go, jsonb, go-gorm

Say I have a table 'testing' with a column 'agents' of type `jsonb` that stores an array of agent names

```
> SELECT * FROM testing;
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id                                   | agents              |
|--------------------------------------+---------------------|
| 018d17a4-5418-1f87-f702-3ed8325f4d11 | ["mikel", "arsene"] |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

I can use the `?` operator to find records that have a string as one of the agents.

```
> SELECT * FROM testing WHERE agents ? 'mikel'
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
| id                                   | agents              |
|--------------------------------------+---------------------|
| 018d17a4-5418-1f87-f702-3ed8325f4d11 | ["mikel", "arsene"] |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+
```

However, in gorm the `?` also acts as a placeholder. So I can't form the query as

```golang
query := `SELECT * FROM testing WHERE agents ? ?
gorm.Raw(query, 'mikel')
```

will produce the raw query

```sql
SELECT * FROM testing WHERE agents 'mikel' ?
```

I know I could use the `@>` operator to achieve this but I would like to know how I can specifically use the `?` operator

Comment: That's not an operator in SQL, it's a positional parameter placeholder. This isn't a gorm feature. Most ODBC drivers work that way. What database are you using? PostgreSQL ?

Comment: Did you try using a named argument instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jsonb existential operators with parameterised queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30461558/jsonb-existential-operators-with-parameterised-queries)

Comment: As the duplicate shows, you can use `jsonb_exists` instead of `?`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes that's an operator in Postgres (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html).

Comment: In *PostgreSQL* only, which you didn't tag. It's also the positional parameter placeholder in the ODBC drivers for *most* databases, no matter the programming language. I only suspected you use PostgreSQL because you mentioned `@>`. Did you check the duplicate?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's interesting and will solve my issue. However, I am specifically looking to see if I can use the `?` operator itself just out of curiosity. I have solved using  `@>` operator in my case.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I immediately edited my question & mentioned Postgres in the title. Maybe you read it before the edit :)

Comment: @Eldar just tried named arg and the `?` operator is simply erased by gorm.

Comment: Use the correct tags instead of editing the title. Only tags are used to notify people interested in PostgreSQL. That's why the people that typically answer PostgreSQL questions haven't showed up yet

Comment: If you switch from `?` to any equivalent function, you'll lose index support - those are tied to [operator classes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING). [I think `postgres` was in the title from the start.](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77832903/1) Did you try [duplicating the `?` to `??`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42819531/escaping-question-mark-in-hibernate-gorm-sql-restriction) or even [`???`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45340238/how-to-use-question-mark-in-query)?

Comment: @Zegarek ya I tried duplicating, but both `??` were erased by gorm.